# Convert from a string to datetime

Tags: c#

First of all I have a xamdatetimeeditor which is for user to select the date and time. It is in the format of "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss". From there, I would like to convert it to "yyyyMMddHHmmss" format. Which means just removing the special characters and spaces.

Do I have to use the DateTime.TryParseExact method? Or do I have to use the string replace function? What is the best solution?

**FOUND THE SOLUTION!!** just have to use string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"; and date = getdate.ToString(format);

Comment: what is the datatype of the current value? is it date or string?

Comment: shouldn't that control be returning a Datetime? ( rather than a string)

Comment: If you just want to replace the special characters and spaces, why don't you just do that?

Comment: Yes, the control will return a DateTime. It's okay now. I found the answer. I just have to use string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"; and date = getdate.ToString(format);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var input = "2004/01/02 12:01:03";
DateTime aDate;
DateTime.TryParse(input, out aDate);
string output = aDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Comment: Yes... that's similar to what I was able to come out with earlier. Thanks though!